# Want to get maximum records which have common rows in related table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables in laravel, one is a middle table :

CREATE TABLE orders( id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, order_number VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE products( id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE orders_products ( order_id INT(10) NOT NULL, product_id INT(10) NOT NULL );

I want to retrive the top two orders which have common products, the higher number is irrelevant here,

What counts is that orderC which has 5 orders, 1,3,4,5,7 and orderF which have also 1,2,3,4,5,6,8 so they have 1,3,4,5 in common, this is what I want to have, even if others have one 2,7,9,12,13,15,17,23 and other 2,4,6,8,9,11,12,14,15,16,17 that is not what I want, but the ones have the most products in common

Many Thanks

This is giving inaccurate results:

```
  $orders = 
  DB::table('orders')
 ->select('orders.id as ordid', 'orders.order_number as order_number',

     DB::raw('COUNT(orders_products.product_id) as counter'  )  )
    ->join('orders_products', 'orders.id', '=', 'orders_products.order_id')
    ->join('products as prod1', 'prod1.id', '=', 

     'orders_products.product_id')
    ->join('products as prod2', 'prod1.id', '=', 'prod2.id')
    ->groupBy(  'orders.order_number')
    ->orderByRaw('MAX(orders_products.product_id) DESC')

    ->limit(2)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the orders with the highest amount of products, you need to use `HAVING` clause and a subquery to get desired results.

The query below works like this:

1. First, a subquery (with a nested subquery) finds the *highest amount of products in a single order* - the `highest_amount` value
2. Then a wrapping query finds all orders, that have *as many products in order as the highest amount* from a subquery.

It would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
   orders.id as ordid, 
   orders.order_number as order_number, 
   COUNT(orders_products.product_id) as counter
FROM orders
JOIN orders_products ON orders.id = orders_products.order_id
JOIN products ON products.id = orders_products.product_id
GROUP BY orders.order_number
HAVING COUNT(orders_products.product_id) >= (
   SELECT MAX(products_in_order) as highest_amount FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(orders_products.product_id) as products_in_order
      FROM orders
      JOIN orders_products ON orders.id = orders_products.order_id
      JOIN products ON products.id = orders_products.product_id
      GROUP BY orders.order_number
   ) top_amounts
)
```

I tested it in this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6812d7/1) - it works as expected (you get all orders with the most products - 3 in this case)

Comment: I think this is great, but do you think you can send it in laravel style? Deeply appreciated

Comment: And I need two records, I checked it, it works fine but gives one record only

Comment: I checked it, this is not working, I need the rows of a common table, top two that have the most product_id in the middle table

Comment: I do not need a query with the highest number of products, what I need is a query that brings two orders who have the highest numver of products that are liek each other

Comment: This is a different topic then, and since you didn't specify what makes the products "like each other", then I can't help you.
And for making this "Laravel style" - I believe it's not easy to do, but have a look at the docs and Laracasts.

Comment: This is what I mean like each other
Order C had 4,5,7,9,11,13 and Order D 4,5,7,8,11 so they have 4,5,7,11 in Common so that makes them a match

Comment: So you mean all orders that have at least one product in common? And you want all such orders, sorted by which order pairs have the most common products?